# Just installed elementary OS. How to get MySQl and C++ to work?

Tags: release-freya, programming

I'm planning on coding using the distro. Which packages should i install?

Answer (score 3):

install the **g++**, **mysql-server** and **mysql-client** packages, you can do that like this.

`sudo apt-get install g++ mysql-server mysql-client`

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Let's see.

The package `build-essential` installs the C and C++ compilers along with the `make` tool and some headers.

You'll need `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` to have a local database and access it. You can try `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-client` too.

For the MySQL C++ connector/driver, there's the `libmysqlcppconn-dev` package. You'll need to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450464/undefined-reference-to-get-driver-instance/11879650#11879650) `-lmysqlcppconn` to the linker when compiling.

So... this should do:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlcppconn-dev`